# GridView DataFormatString problems. convert Doudle to TimeStamp

Tags: c#, asp.net

Need some help with DataFormatString in GridView. I have a Double value that needs to be shown as TimeSpan. I have tried DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm:ss}". This did not work.

Tested it a bit in C# and there I would do:

```
TimeSpan.FromHours(16.7358217592592).ToString()
```

This gives me.

```
"16:44:08.9580000"
```

Which is what i am after. But how to get it in ASP.Net is the big question.
Any Suggestions?

I have a simple GridView that looks like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="sOprTime" HeaderText="Sum OprTime" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="sOprTime" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="sWorkTime" HeaderText="Sum WorkTime" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="sWorkTime" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="sFaultTime" HeaderText="Sum FaultTime" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="sFaultTime" />
</Columns>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    No data is present.
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

The SQL query looks like this:

```
sqlString1 = string.Format(@"SELECT SUM(CONVERT (Float, OprTime)) AS sOprTime, SUM(CONVERT (Float, WorkTime)) AS sWorkTime, SUM(CONVERT (Float, OprTime)) - SUM(CONVERT (Float, WorkTime)) AS sFaultTime FROM tblNovikLogg WHERE (Date_Time > '{0:yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss}' And Date_Time < '{1:yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss}')",  selectedDate, selectedDate.AddDays(1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that in [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx):

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        Double sWorkTime = row.Field<Double>("sWorkTime");
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(sWorkTime);
        String formattedTimespan = String.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm\:ss}", ts);
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = formattedTimespan;
    }
}
```